# Visual Studio Code Standard Logic Apps Editing existing logic app

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I wonder if someone can give me some advice. I want to know if it is at all possible to edit a current standard logic app in VS Code. I can see it in the designer but not allowed to edit at all. Is this a limitation in VS Code?

Comment: I just tried to do it for a consumption app and hitting Ctrl+S wants to upload it back to Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to File -> Save or a simple simple ctrl+S should work fine.

[image]

---

## **Updated Answer**

This behavior happens because after you open a logic app's .json file, Visual Studio caches the subscription for future use. To resolve this You can create another logic app and copy the json content from the workflow you are looking at, save it to your newly created logic app workflow and then deploy the new logic app to your old one

Comment: I have existing standard logic apps in Azure.  I can see them in the designer in VS Code but cannot edit them or save them. So just wondering if this is a limitation in VS Code.

Comment: This behavior happens because after you open a logic app's .json file, Visual Studio caches the subscription for future use. To resolve this You can create another logic app and copy the json content from the workflow you are looking at, save it to your newly created logic app workflow and then deploy the new logic app to your old one.